# Retirar duplicados de Duas colunas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Então, a situação é a seguinte, eu tenho uma **tabela** e nela tenho três campos, sendo assim eu preciso comparar o (**a** = **b**) e achar se tem alguém igual.
Qual o meu problema, sou nova no meio do sql e não estou conseguindo ter certeza se fiz certo, tentei das seguintes formas.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [a]
               ,[b]
     FROM [Compara] -- 1 °




SELECT [a]
      ,[b]
     FROM [Compara]

WHERE [a] = [b] --2°
```

Nenhum teve retorno, sendo assim não sei se fiz certo ou errado, se alguém puder me ajudar >.<

Comment: Brenda bem vinda ao SO-pt. Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, poderia mostrar a estrutura da sua tabela com alguns dados e colocar uma resultado que deseja ? Clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/273448/edit) Recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais como funciona as coisas aqui na rede!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A = B THEN 'Coluna A igual a B' ELSE 'Coluna A diferente da B' END AS COMPARATIVO_01
  FROM TABELA
```

O `SELECT` acima vai retornar todos os dados da tabela (pois eu não utilizei o `WHERE`), mas em compensação, ele retornará se os registros da coluna A são diferentes do da coluna B, isso comparado por linha.

Agora se você quer apenas retornar os registros em que a coluna `A` é diferente de `B`, utilize a instrução abaixo:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABELA
 WHERE A <> B;
```

Ou para saber se são iguais:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABELA
 WHERE A = B;
```

**Editado**

Coloquei as três condições para ficar claro ao usuário as possíveis possibilidades de SQL.

**Atenção:** Como você disse que ainda está aprendendo `SQL`, tome cuidado para não fazer comparação de colunas de dados diferentes. Como comparar `TRUE` ou `FALSE` com `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Muito obrigada Lucas ^^,  e nesse caso as duas colunas estão com com o mesmo tipo, no caso VARCHAR.